# Why do I need to use &str when defining a string literal in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, reference

Why can I not use `str` here?

```
let question: &str = "why";
```

What's the difference between `str` and `&str`?

I get that `&` denotes a reference, but I'm confused about what `&str` is referencing.

Comment: Neither ``(&str)`` nor ``("why")`` denote tuples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `str` is a sequence of UTF-8 encoded bytes *of unknown length*, somewhere in memory.

Because its size is not known at compile time, it can't be put on the stack directly, instead, a reference must be used.

A string literal (i.e. the `"why"` syntax) creates a space in the data segment of the binary, and returns **a reference to that location**, which is an `&str` (in particular, an `&'static str`, because it is never dropped).

If you write `let question: str = "why";`, this won't compile for the same reason: `let i: i32 = &123;` won't compile.

P.S. `("hello")` is not a tuple, it is just a `&str` in brackets. If you want to make a tuple with a single element, add a trailing comma: `let hello: (&str,) = ("hello",)`;

Comment: Where is "that location", is it in the ROM2?